# backbone.js: what is the significance of a slash at the end of a url?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Sort of a noobie question...

In the final line of this function, I understand the code is trying to figure out the final character of 'base' and then, using the ternary structure,  if it's `'/'` adding the empty string, but if it's not `/`then it's adding the slash, as well as, in either case, the id.

The part I don't understand is what the significance of the slash or the lack of the slash would be at the end of base. i.e. what does it say about the url and why would we need to determine if the slash is there? under what circumstances would it be there? Under what circumstances wouldn't it?

Note, I looked in the documentation but couldn't find a clear explanation of this

```
var Document = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : function() {
      var base = 'documents';
      if (this.isNew()) return base;
      return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.id;
    }
});
```

I got this code from the following tutorial but it doesn't fully explain the issue
http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular instance looks pointless, as you already know that `'documents'` doesn't have a slash on the end.  If you didn't know that `base` equaled `'documents'`, then it would ensure that there is a path seperator between `base` and `this.id`.